# how do I get a random 4 digit number that can only have digits from 1 to 9?

Tags: python, python-3.9

In between every random number, the user has to input the sum, before the next 4 digit number comes. This has to happen 3 times.

This is my code thus far:

```py
import string
from random import choice
chars = string.digits
random =  ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(4))
print (random)

first = input('Try 1, sum the digits: ')

chars = string.digits
random =  ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(4))
print (random)

second = input('Try 2, sum the digits: ')

chars = string.digits
random =  ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(4))
print (random)

third = input('Try 3, sum the digits: ')
```

How do I ensure it does not have 0 in the digits of all 3 tries? And is there a way to make it simpler?

Comment: but there can't be any 0 in any of the 4 digits

Comment: I don't understand why you include 0 in the characters to start with, just use 1-9.

Comment: sorry, where should I include that in?

Comment: I would suggest _debugging_ the code you have, it should be very obvious where the 0 is coming from.

Comment: `chars = "123456789"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have this line several times in the code:

```py
chars = string.digits
```

`string.digits` is equal to `0123456789` so notably there is a zero in there. This means that zero will frequently come up in randomly generated numbers.

You can solve this by changing those three lines to be:

```py
chars = "123456789"
```

You also asked if this code could be simplified. The thing that stands out is that you essentially have the same code repeated three times, so the best way to simplify this code is to use a loop instead. This will allow you to have the code written just once, but execute three times.

The loop would be implemented like this:

```py
from random import choice

chars = "123456789"
for n in range(3):    
    random = ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(4))
    print (random)
    answer = input('Try ' + str(n + 1) + ', sum the digits: ')
```

Some other suggestions would be to combine the print line with the input line, because this will make for a more understandable output for the user. Like so:

```py
from random import choice

chars = "123456789"
for n in range(3):    
    random = ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(4))
    answer = input('Try ' + str(n + 1) + ', sum the digits in ' + str(random) + ': ')
```

Another thing I would do is to use `choices` instead of `choice`, because you can directly tell that to return 4 items. That simplifies the random generation. That would be:

```
from random import choices

chars = "123456789"
for n in range(3):
    random = ''.join(choices(chars, k=4))
    answer = input('Try ' + str(n + 1) + ', sum the digits in ' + str(random) + ': ')
```

One thing that is missing from this code is a way to tell the user if they were correct. You can do that like this:

```py
from random import choices

chars = "123456789"
for n in range(3):
    digits = choices(chars, k=4)
    answer = str(sum(int(a) for a in digits))
    number = ''.join(digits)
    guess = input('Try ' + str(n + 1) + ', sum the digits in ' + str(number) + ': ')
    if answer == guess:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Wrong! The answer was " + str(answer))
```

An example output using that final code is:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your comprehensive comments. It really helped me as I am new to coding. I am going to try it out, but just to reiterate how appreciative I am for your help.